Flutter webView: how to pass parameters in loadRequst body?
Try to pass parameters a=1&b=2 to the WebView URI:
Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080');
var body = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode('a=1&b=2')));

WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
       ..loadRequest(uri, body: body);
     
WebViewWidget(controller: controller);

On server side parameter a and b are null.

Have you tried http://localhost:8080?a=1&b=2 ?

Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080?a=1&b=2');

It works in URL, but not in body.
